# Use default styling in custom plot function

Tags: plotting, customization

I have a set of velocity vectors that I'd like to plot as if I'd used [`ListVectorPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListVectorPlot3D.html).

Of course, I can't use `ListVectorPlot3D` as I don't have a true vector field to interpolate over, but rather just a discrete set of vectors.

Is there a nice way to access all of the styling conveniences of `ListVectorPlot3D` on this?

In general, if we can't build on top of an `` "System`" `` function, can we still build custom plot functions that make use of internal plotting convenience functions without handling the myriad little subcases ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to, at a minimum, include plot styling on our custom functions:

```
applyPlotTheming[
  coreData_,
  baseFunction_,
  inheritFrom_,
  o : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 Module[
  {
   inheritBase = Flatten[{inheritFrom}][[1]],
   theme,
   premethod,
   method,
   defaultstyle,
   defaultcf,
   cf,
   opts
   },
  opts = 
   Flatten @ {o};
  Quiet[
   theme = OptionValue[inheritFrom, opts, PlotTheme]
   ];
  theme = Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[theme, inheritBase];
  Quiet[premethod = Quiet@ OptionValue[inheritBase, theme, Method]];
  premethod = Charting`ConstructMethod@ premethod;
  theme = FilterRules[theme, Except @ Method];
  theme =
    FilterRules[
    theme,
    Join @@ Map[Options, Flatten[{inheritFrom}]]
    ];
  opts = Flatten[{opts, theme}];
  method = Quiet@OptionValue[inheritFrom, opts, Method];
  method =
   Charting`parseMethod[
    Charting`ConstructMethod@method,
    premethod
    ];
  {defaultstyle, defaultcf, cf} =
    Quiet @ 
    OptionValue[
     inheritFrom,
     Flatten @ {method, opts},
     {"DefaultPlotStyle", "DefaultColorFunction", ColorFunction}
     ];
  cf = Charting`customColorFunction[inheritBase, cf, defaultcf];
  opts =
   Join[
    opts,
    {
     "DefaultPlotStyle" -> defaultstyle,
     ColorFunction -> cf
     }
    ];
  baseFunction[
   coreData,
   Charting`FilterGraphicsOptions[
    Flatten@{opts, Method -> method},
    Options@baseFunction
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

I stole most of that code from the `DownValues` of `` System`VectorPlotsDump`iListVectorPlot3D ``.

Then if we want to use this we can make a low-level function that really just handles making some `Graphics3D` objects:

```
Options[customArrows3D] =
  Join[
   Options[ListVectorPlot3D],
   Options[System`VectorPlotsDump`iListVectorPlot3D],
   Charting`$GraphicsExtraOptions
   ];
customArrows3D[{coords_, vels_},  ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {
   velNorms = Norm /@ vels, 
   velMax,
   boxSize = 
    Max@{-(Subtract @@ MinMax@CoordinateBounds[coords]), .001},
   defps = OptionValue["DefaultPlotStyle"],
   cf =
    Replace[
     Charting`customColorFunction[
      ListVectorPlot3D,
      OptionValue[VectorColorFunction],
      OptionValue["DefaultColorFunction"]
      ],
     cd_ColorDataFunction :> (cd[#] &)
     ],
   velVecs,
   ps,
   hackColorMap
   },
  velMax = Max@velNorms;
  ps =
   Charting`customVectorStyle[ 
     OptionValue[VectorStyle],
     defps,
     1
     ][[1]];
  If[velMax != 0,
   velVecs = Thread[{coords, coords + vels*(boxSize/10/velMax)}];
   hackColorMap =
    If[cf === None,
     Nothing,
     Association@
      MapThread[
       #[[1]] -> (cf @@ Flatten[Prepend[##]]) &,
       {
        If[OptionValue@VectorColorFunctionScaling,
         Rescale@velVecs,
         velVecs
         ],
        If[OptionValue@VectorColorFunctionScaling,
         Rescale@velNorms,
         velNorms
         ]
        }
       ]
     ],
   hackColorMap =
    AssociationMap[Nothing,  Rescale@coords]
   ];
  Show[
   ListPointPlot3D[coords,
    FilterRules[
     Flatten@
      {
       ColorFunctionScaling ->
        OptionValue@VectorColorFunctionScaling,
       ColorFunction ->
        If[cf =!= None,
         With[{nf = Nearest[Keys@hackColorMap]},
          hackColorMap[nf[{#, #2, #3}][[1]]] &
          ],
         cf
         ],
       ops,
       PlotStyle -> ps,
       BoxRatios -> Automatic
       }, 
     Options@ListPointPlot3D
     ]
    ],
   If[velMax != 0,
    Graphics3D[
     MapThread[
      Flatten@*List,
      {
       Replace[Quiet@OptionValue[VectorScale],
        {
         Automatic :>

          Thread@Arrowheads[velNorms/velMax/25, 
            Appearance -> "Projected"],
         n : _?NumericQ :>

          Thread@Arrowheads[n*velNorms/velMax, 
            Appearance -> "Projected"],
         _ :>
          ConstantArray[
           Arrowheads[Appearance -> "Projected"],
           Length@velNorms
           ]
         }
        ],
       ConstantArray[ps, Length@velNorms],
       If[cf === None,
        Nothing,
        Values@hackColorMap
        ],
       Thread[Arrow@velVecs]
       }
      ],
     FilterRules[{ops}, Options@Graphics3D]
     ],
    {}
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Note my use of some other functions poached from the `DownValues`: `` Charting`customColorFunction `` and `` Charting`customVectorStyle ``

And then by wrapping it we can make a function with better handling of theming and stuff:

```
myLVP3D[data_, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 applyPlotTheming[
  data,
  customArrows3D,
  {ListVectorPlot3D, System`VectorPlotsDump`iListVectorPlot3D},
  ops
  ]
```

And here that is in action:

```
mydats =
  BlockRandom[
   SeedRandom[100];
   {
    RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {100, 3}],
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 3}]
    }
   ];

Grid[
 {
  myLVP3D[mydats, PlotTheme -> #, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ {Automatic, 
    "Scientific", "Marketing"},
  myLVP3D[mydats, VectorColorFunction -> #, 
     ImageSize -> 250] & /@
   {"Rainbow", "AlpineColors", "DarkBands"}
  }
 ]
```

[image: boop]

Note one major issue with this, which is that the `Ticks` in every case except for the `"Scientific"` theme are coming from the `ListPointPlot3D`.